# sub-subdomain wildcard redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Using wildcard dns / apache / mod-rewrite, I want to achieve the following:

clientname.clients.company.com -> /home/company.com/clients/clientname

I've tried rewrite rules, such as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.clients\.company\.com
RewriteCond /home/clients\.company\.com/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1/$1 [L]
```

none of them seem to work with the *.clients.company.com model - I'm getting an infinite loop error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're basically trying to setup [dynamically configured mass virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html). A simpler configuration would be to use [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html). The `%1` substitution will contain the first part of the hostname, so the following will set the document root appropriately.

```
UseCanonicalName    Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /home/company.com/clients/%1
```

(You could actually avoid hardcoding most of the path with `/home/%3-/%2/%1`.)

Comment: Great, I'll give that a shot today - thank you for your suggestion.